# cpp: get param from configuration file and use it in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

I'm sure this is a topic that is dealt quite a lot, but couldn't find my answer.

I'd like to construct an object based on a value parsed from a JSON file.

For example, a "class doubleBuffer" which gets its size from a configuration file.

But this object resides as a member in another class (class client), which by the time it parses the JSON, the doubleBuffer field in it is already constructed.

```
class doubleBuffer {
   int _size = 0;
   uint8_t _buf = nullptr;
   doubleBuffer(int size) : _size(size) {
         _buf = new (uint8_t[_size]);
   }
   doubleBuffer() {}
}

class client {
   doubleBuffer _db;
   int _size = 0;
public:
   void client() { 
      readConfiguration();  // _size is set from the configuration file
   }
   void readConfiguration() { ... }
}

int main() {
   client cl;
   // here, the configuration file is already parsed,
   // but the _db field has been constructed with a default ctor.
   // And what I'd like to happen is to construct it from the size,
   // parsed in the configuration file.
   return 0;
}
```

How would you recommend to solve this problem?

Comment: I would change variable names because symbols with leading underscores are reserved for the compiler or platform.  Maybe change the member names to have a "m_" prefix.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews If the second character is not an underscore or upper-case letter the identifier is reserved only in the global namespace scope.

Comment: Is there a reason that your `client` contains two `int _size` variables?  Are they intended to hold the same value?

Comment: Do you know what a constructor initialization section is, and how to use it?

Comment: Inside a class you need underscore followed by capital letter to set off Thomas's warning. Details: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/4581301) I avoid leading underscore out of general principles because I've found too many people screw it up anyway.

Comment: _"a value parsed from a JSON file"_ - then create a simple compiler that transforms the JSON data into C++ code, like `inline constexpr size_t db_buf_size = 2048;`, and put that in a file that can be parsed by the C++ compiler. You can easily integrate your "JSON" compiler into the build.

Comment: *which by the time it parses the JSON, the doubleBuffer field in it is already constructed.* This order must be corrected. I find a helper function called to initialize a member variable (and you're storing that parsed JSON file somewhere, and that somewhere should be somebody's member variable) in the [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) solves this problem most of the time.

Comment: Side note: members are always initialized in the order they are declared no matter the order of the members in the initializer list.

Comment: Neither the default constructor nor the constructor you're asking about could be called from , since both are private and `doubleBuffer` has no friends... And if you ever want to properly free the allocated resources, you should definetly get rid of those implicitly defined defaulted move/copy semantics...

Answer (score 3):

Read the JSON file to a *JSON object*.

Pass the object as an argument to the constructor of `client`. Fetch branches of the json and pass them down to subobjects' constructors, like this:

```
class client {
    int _size;
    doubleBuffer _db;
  public:       
    client (const JSON& config) : 
          _size(config.get<int>("size")),
          _db(_size) { ... }
};

JSON config;
config.read(".config.json");
client cl(config);
```

(I invented the `JSON` class API on the fly, use whatever your library provides)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 choices:

- parse the JSON *before* you construct the `client`.  Pass the parsed result into the `client`'s constructor, and then let it delegate the parsed values to member constructors as needed.
- Have `client` parse the JSON as you are, but then construct the `doubleBuffer` dynamically *after* the parsing is finished.  Or, default-construct the `doubleBuffer`, and then add a method to `doubleBuffer` so you can resize its `_buf` dynamically after the JSON is parsed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rework it a bit. You probably don't want to read the configuration every time you instantiate a `client` - or re-read the configuration for any other object that needs some parameter from the configuration file. Read it once and use it many times.

With most Json libraries you can also add parsers for your own types, which makes it easy to get the data out into a format that doesn't need to be parsed and re-parsed every time you need something from it. Here's an example using the [Json for Modern C++](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) library.

Say your `config.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "application": "My soft config",
    "db_buf_size": 2048
}
```

And you want this available to your application stored in a

```cpp
struct config_data {
    std::string application;
    std::size_t db_buf_size;
};
```

You'd simply add a `from_json` function to make the library able to parse it:

```cpp
void from_json(const nlohmann::json& obj, config_data& c) {
    c.application = obj.at("application").get<std::string>();
    c.db_buf_size = obj.at("db_buf_size").get<std::size_t>();
}
```

You also need a function that you can call at any time that returns a reference to the loaded configuration and here's an example of a function named `config()` that returns a reference to a `config_data`. Since the `config_data` instance is `static` it will only read and parse the configuration from file once, no matter how many calls to `config()` you do:

```cpp
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <filesystem>
#include <stdexcept>

const config_data& config() {
    static const config_data conf = [] {
        std::filesystem::path path = "config.json";
        std::ifstream ifs(path);
        if(!ifs)
            throw std::runtime_error(path.string() + ": " +
                                     std::strerror(errno));
        auto j = json::parse(ifs);
        return j.get<config_data>(); // using the user defined parser
    }();

    return conf;
}
```

You can now let the `client` constructor call `config()` and fetch any value from the configuration. Again, since the actual `config_data` instance in the `config()` function is `static`, actually loading and parsing the data will only done once.

```cpp
class doubleBuffer {
public:
    doubleBuffer(size_t size) : m_size(size), m_buf{new uint8_t[m_size]} {}

    doubleBuffer(const doubleBuffer&) = delete;
    doubleBuffer(doubleBuffer&&) = delete;
    ~doubleBuffer() { delete[] m_buf; }

    size_t size() const { return m_size; }

private:
    size_t m_size = 0;
    uint8_t* m_buf = nullptr;
};

class client {
public:
    client() : m_db(config().db_buf_size) {}  // fetch the needed data

    size_t size() const { return m_db.size(); }

private:
    doubleBuffer m_db;
};
```

You may also want to consider using a `std::vector<uint8_t>` instead of a raw `uint8_t*`.